Angular + RxJS + Esri Feature Layer queryFeatures - applyEdits operations pipe & retry operation
I am trying to build an application where vpn connection plays a critical role so if a user disconnects from its vpn i would like to keep try to query or try to apply edit to feature layer if vpn somehow gets connected again. Here is that i have tried so far
    const testFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer({ url: LAYERDETAILS.TEST.url})
    var query = testFeatureLayer.createQuery();
    query.where = '1=1'
    query.outFields = ['*']
    from(testFeatureLayer.queryFeatures(query)).pipe(
      retry({
        count:50,
        delay: 1000, // 2 second delay between retries
        resetOnSuccess: true
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Failed after all retries:', error);
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        console.log('Query response:', response);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Final error:', error);
      }
    });

Here is Esri Feature Layer;
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html
This method query features - > (method) __esri.FeatureLayer.queryFeatures(query?: __esri.Query | __esri.QueryProperties, options?: __esri.FeatureLayerQueryFeaturesOptions): Promise<__esri.FeatureSet>
I have tried doing it with from, or with of but i got not luck.

Okay so, i was able to come up with a code like this not sure if its best way to do it but this does it for now, if anyone wants to improve it please be my guest i would really appreciate it.
  async retryEsriLayer(): Promise<any> {
let retryCount = 0;
const maxRetries = 50;
while (retryCount < maxRetries) {
  try {
    const testFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer({ url: LAYERDETAILS.SUREC_W_USERS.url })
    var query = testFeatureLayer.createQuery();
    query.where = '1=1'
    query.outFields = ['*']

    const result = await lastValueFrom(
      from(testFeatureLayer.queryFeatures(query)).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {

          console.error(`Error during query attempt ${retryCount + 1}:`, error);
          throw error;
        })
      )
    );
    return result;
  }
  catch (error) {
    retryCount++;
    console.warn(`Retry ${retryCount} failed. Retrying...`);

    if (retryCount >= maxRetries) {
      console.error('Max retries reached:', error);
      throw error;
    }

    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000));
  }
}

}
